# how to have a summulation for olimpique race in python

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

hello i have a problem in a project that asking a stimulation for a olympique race
Required in the exercise
is creating a 30 process and they have to do a calculate in 10 rounds every 5 process finishing their job starting a round  till they ( so the condition to start a round is having a 5 process ) and every process when he Finnish the job he have to show his solution for the problem
if process 10 Finnish he shows
( process 10 solution's round 5 : x = 6) for example
when i was trying to do that i had some problems like some variables never change
like the process counter and the next round
you can see that in my code
any help to fix the code please
and thank you
the code :
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from functools import reduce

```
import random
import os
import pandas as pd
# from mpi4py import MPI

global solNb, nextRound, lastRound, target, procNB, nonce, broadcast, END, countProcess, sols, lock, roundID
solNb = 5
nextRound = 1
lastRound = 10
procNB = 30
END = False
lock = False

sols = 0
roundID = 0
nonce = 1
x = random.randint(0, 1000)
q = Queue(solNb)
target = 200
xs = []
rndIDs = []
nonces = []
data = {'x': xs, 'rndID': rndIDs, 'nonce': nonces}

broadcast = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=int)


#data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
#df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])


def checksum256(st):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(ord, st)) % 256


def Broadcast_round(nxtRnd, rndID):
    global nextRound, roundID
    # broadcast2.loc[len(broadcast2.index)] = [nxtRnd, rndID]
    nextRound = nxtRnd
    roundID = rndID


def Broadcast_result(x, rnID, nonc):
    global countProcess, broadcast, lock
    lock = True
    broadcast.loc[len(broadcast.index)] = [x, rnID, nonc]
    print(broadcast)

countProcess = 0
def processWork(p):
    global nextRound, lastRound, nonce, broadcast, x, roundID, END, xs, rndIDs, nonces, sols, countProcess, lock
    print('-------------------------------')
    print(f'ProcessID: {os.getpid()}')

    while nextRound <= lastRound:
        
        print(f'next round:{nextRound}')
        while checksum256(str(nonce) + str(roundID) + str(x)) > target:
            nonce = nonce + 1
            print(f'{nonce}')
        if nextRound == lastRound and not END:  # END == False
            END = True
            print("I am the winner")
        Broadcast_result(x, roundID, nonce)  # function for sending mes
        countProcess = countProcess+1
        q.put(nonce)
        while sols < solNb:
            if countProcess >= 0 and lock:  # processWait(xRcv, roundIDRcv, nonceRcv):
                print('countprocess', p)
                lock = False
                if checksum256(str(broadcast.loc[countProcess-1, 'x']) + str(broadcast.loc[countProcess-1, 'rndID']) + str(broadcast.loc[countProcess-1, 'nonce'])) < target:
                    sols = sols + 1
                    q.put(broadcast.loc[countProcess-1, 'nonce'])  # put(nonce)
                    print(sols)
        sols = 0
        nextRound = nextRound + 1
        sumNonce = 0
        for i in q:
            sumNonce = sumNonce + q.get()
        RoundID = sumNonce
        print("=============================================== nextround and ID", nextRound, RoundID)
        Broadcast_round(nextRound, RoundID)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    procList = []
    for p in range(procNB):
        print("===========================")
        process = Process(target=processWork, name=f'Process-{p}')
        process.start()
        procList.append(process)

    for p in range(procNB):
        procList[p].join()
```